# How to get current overall cpu usage in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-service

I want a method to get the current overall cpu usage in android! I used a method that I found in this site and it's stated below.

```
private float readUsage() {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/stat", "r");
        String load = reader.readLine();

        String[] toks = load.split(" ");

        long idle1 = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);
        long cpu1 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[4])
              + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(360);
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        reader.seek(0);
        load = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();

        toks = load.split(" ");

        long idle2 = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);
        long cpu2 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[4])
            + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

        return (float)(cpu2 - cpu1) / ((cpu2 + idle2) - (cpu1 + idle1));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But this method only returns me one float value. what I need is the current usage statistics like the percentage used by the system, and the percentage used by the user! can any one help me with this. a tutorial would be nice, but if any one is generous enough to give me a good code It would be my pleasure!

thank you!

Comment: "percentage used by the system, and the percentage used by the user" How would you make a distinction? The user is the one controlling the system, they are essentially the system. I guess I am not understanding your terminology.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.advancedprocessmanager

Comment: exactly what the aove application does! :)

Answer (score 0):

From the linux proc manual page:

> /proc/stat
>                 kernel/system statistics.   Varies  with  architecture.   Common
>                 entries include:
>
> ```
>           cpu  3357 0 4313 1362393
>                  The   amount  of  time,  measured  in  units  of  USER_HZ
>                  (1/100ths  of  a  second  on  most   architectures,   use
>                  sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK) to obtain the right value), that the
>                  system spent in user mode, user mode  with  low  priority
>                  (nice),  system  mode,  and  the idle task, respectively.
>                  The last value should be USER_HZ times the  second  entry
>                  in the uptime pseudo-file.
> ```

You may also want to look at the source of 'top' in AOSP platform/system/core/toolbox

Answer (score 0):

When you are looking at the statistics in "proc/stat"

- it will provide you with the overall CPU Usage (Kernal Mode+ User Mode)
- you can only get the CPU USAGE in terms of system & user mode per process proc/[pid]/stat
       - 14th param :- user mode in jiffies
       - 15th param :- kernal mode in jiffies
- calculate the Kernel Mode Usage for all the processes/pids and can consider it as system CPU usage...